How to send a POST response without terminating the execution flow
I have a Google appscript set up which serves as a webhook for the incoming POST requests. I want to make several operations on the data that I have recieved in the POST request before saving it to the Google sheet. The appscript works perfectly but the execution time is around 10 secs. To reduce the wait time for the response I want to notify the POST request after doing a basic check of the data that I have recieved and then continue with my rest of the operations. How should I go about doing it?
The biggest issue I want to solve is to somehow notify the server that I recieved the post request and the data is OK(status 200), without using return statement. cause the return statement terminates the execution flow. Thus, for now I am keeping return(POST response) part at the last and doing every operations before notifying the server that I recived the POST request.

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand The biggest issue I want to solve is to somehow notify the server that I recieved the post request and the data is OK(status 200), without using return statement.. Can I ask you about the details of your current issue and your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.
